# Rigid 4x4 keypad decoder - voltage drop

Tags: keypad

I am trying to implement a keypad decoder: it has 8 digital outputs, 4 that indicate the row of the pressed button, and the other 4 associated with columns. There are green LEDs that serve as a visual indicator.
I have worked with the scanning algorithm before, but wanted to go for something different this time. Here is the design I made in circuitjs and Proteus, with a 10mA current for each LED in mind, it works perfectly:
[image]

Each optoisolator has a pull-up resistor output, that gives 0 when the associated row is pressed; the same idea is used on the 2n2222a transistors, they give 0 at the output when its column is pressed, There is a group of capacitors for debouncing, and I intend to use a schmitt trigger to smoothen the signal.

In circuitjs, this is my representation of the keypad with my circuit (15k base resistor works fine, like 10k in Proteus):
[image]

The keypad I am using is:
[image]

I have implemented my circuit in a protoboard, following the same wiring, due to lack of components I am scanning one button at a time, alternating row and column pins; for the buttons that belong to the first row, the LEDs turn on as expected, however for the other rows, I see a voltage drop between the column and row pin (between 1V and 1.8V, depending on the LED color used), this drop causes the 2n2222a to not "turn on", not allowing its column LED to activate.

Any ideas on why this happens? Simulation works as intended.

EDIT: This is my circuit:
[image]

The black jumper wire is connected to C1 pin from keypad, the yellow one to Row1. Opto is a 4N25.

Comment: Just skimming quickly above, is it fair to say that all your simulation attempts show good results that you like but that when you actually built it up on a solderless breadboard it's not doing what you think the simulations say it should do? If so, don't you think we should actually see what you built? (That is, supposedly, where the problems lay.)

Comment: Thanks for answering, of course, I will edit the post as soon as possible

Comment: @periblepsis done, please take a look at my circuit and tell me if you need more details. Changed green leds to red since they are the ones I have at hand, the behavior I described still persists the same way

Comment: So, looking [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRrtD.png) would it be correct to say that either a row or a column is connected to pin 2 of the opto? I can't really see where the BJT is connected -- part bodies are in the way. Any chance you can add a quick schematic of just this breadboarded circuit? (Not the whole idea, just this single implementation.) Where do those brown wires head off to on the left?

Comment: As far as just reading your schematics above (not as easy as they could be), I find [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnlXz.png) as a tentative schematic. Is that what you intended? Or am I getting something wrong about that?

Comment: Yes it is, the schematic you provided is precisely my circuit :D

Comment: Bit funky. I guess the idea you have is that after the two LED drops (D2 and U1's LED in my schematic), the switch will pull up on the 220 Ohm enough to cause the BJT (via a 10k resistor) will turn on. Or, say, if there's 10 mA (no idea if so, just tossing a number out) through those LEDs, then the 220 Ohm will have 10 mA times 220 Ohm or about 2.2 V across it. But now, let's assume the BJT needs about 750 mV, Vbe, so this means (2.2-0.75)/10k=145 uA for the BJT. Do you think that is enough for the BJT to saturate out as a switch? Also, 2.2 leaves only 2.8 V for both LEDs mentioned. Not much.

Comment: I know what I'd be doing -- even assuming the use of optos (which I can't say I entirely follow why, but can accept)... I'd likely use a 74HC4017 coupled to some logic (and a fast clock) that would latch up a key for me, provide a `data available` signal, and accept an `async read` to indicate it had been read and therefore allowing another key to be captured. But that's me.

Comment: Yeah it is kinda funky. Yes that is how it is supposed to behave, I am testing it now and there seems to be a voltage drop in the opto's diode though, of about 1V. Measuring the current base, it is 75uA, but it seems to saturate the BJT since both LEDs turn on.

However, when changing to another row, there is a voltage drop across the pins from the button pressed, causing the current to drop as well, so it dosent saturate the BJT, thats as far as I could get with troubleshooting.

Comment: Well, you know there should ***not*** be a voltage drop across the pins when a button is pressed. That's a problem.

Comment: I see, I will look up that IC you mentioned, but still I would like to know the root of the problem, if possible, out of curiosity.

Comment: Could it be a faulty keypad? I read somewhere that the internal resistance from the keypad makes some rows have more resistance than others.

Comment: You ***know*** that there should be no voltage drop across Cx and Ry when the button is pressed, given your circuit design. That's an assumption that goes into your `funky` circuit. If you need to accommodate significant resistance in the contacts, then you need a different circuit. Can you make some measurements of that keypad and verify? Because on one hand you are claiming a voltage drop between Cx and Ry. And that may be ***bad***. However, if resistance is significant, then it may also be "by design." But if so, you have work ahead to accommodate that fact. So you need to measure. Now!

Comment: On it! I will measure said resistance and try to adjust my circuit to it. Thank you so much for your insight, I will come back once I have the results, hopefully I can get some more help by then.

Comment: Contact resistance on these keypads can be as high as 100Ω. You can test in your simulation by adding a 100Ω in series with the column pin. This will reduce the current through the contact to about 7.5mA. You may need to drop the 220 resistor to 120 which will require a corresponding reduction for the 10K to get 10mA. I have not been able to find a wetting current for the keypad so more is better within specification.

Comment: @lachoprime [Here's how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32IBe.png) I might consider using the 74HC4017 device. I haven't explained the lines going off to the right. But the bottom eight of them will be latched when a key is struck. The upper two are for handling the event and interfacing with a remote CPU, with some added logic. The 10 states of the 74HC4017 are divided into four scanning lines and one additional line used to move an async capture into a synchronous buffer.

Comment: @periblepsis it looks really good, I will take a look into it
"@"RussellH So the keypad was the real culprit all along, I have already measured it and corrected my circuit, I am editing the post right now.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it is not a forum. You wrote your solution into your question. This does not help future visitors, actually nobody will find it. Please delete your solution in the question and copy it to an actual answer, which you will mark as "accepted". This way others looking for help will see directly in the list of questions that your issue has an answer that solves the issue.

Comment: @lachoprime  Welcome to the site. We look forward to seeing much more of your input. || I've moved your 'solution' section to the top of your question so others can see that you have found your problem **BUT** as "the busybee" suggested - would you please add your solution as an answer to your own question, and then delete it from the answer. That way it forms a useful question & answer pair for others to learn from - which is the manner in which this soite is meant to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: First, I measured the internal resistance using a simple pull down resistor circuit, using each button from the keypad and measuring the voltage drop across the C and R pins. For row 1, I had to assume a 0.02k resistance for my design (based on results), for row 2, 0.425k, 0.388k for row 3 and 0.582 for row 4. I also forgot to take into consideration the forward voltage from the LED inside the optoisolator. Now, the base voltage of the BJT could never be more than 0.65 to saturate it; but now I knew the root of the problem, so I just moved the LED that corresponds to "n" row to the output of the optoisolator, changed the base resistor to 82k, and it is pulled to ground with a 1k resistor to avoid any fake triggering. Now it works for all pins, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd just suggest something for you to consider in the future. It has just enough features to be generally useful.

#### keypad and scan driver

Here's what I'd start with, with respect to the input pad:

[image]

The columns and rows have pull-ups. I'd probably use \$2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistors for this. The [7445 BCD decoder](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5445.pdf?ts=1707294008210&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) shown above is designed with outputs sporting high-breakdown transistors (\$30\:\text{V}\$) that are able to sink \$80\:\text{mA}\$. (Keeping in mind that with the right set of simultaneous key-presses it is technically possible for **five** of the pull-ups to be active at once.)

The above schematic block accepts a binary input at \$G_0\$ and \$G_1\$. I have wired it above to scan the columns sequentially when provided with the output from a 2-bit twisted-ring Johnson counter.

#### column scanning

I tend to prefer a twisted ring Johnson counter (only one bit changes per state change), other things being equal.

I also like the 7476 over the 7474, perhaps in part because I've used a lot of them over the years and perhaps also in part because they sport async clear and set inputs. In this case, I've added a POR (power-on reset) feeding these JK FFs so that they come up in a known state. It's not necessary (who cares?), but I'm just being pedantic here.

[image]

A 555 timer (CMOS or otherwise) is shown providing the clock for scanning.

At this point, there are three ICs so far: 555 timer, 7445, and 7476. And these together will scan the columns and generate outputs \$C_1\dots C_4\$ and \$R_1\dots R_4\$, which can be captured if any of \$R_1\dots R_4\$ goes **LOW**.

#### recognizing a keypress

Speaking of which, the following circuit uses Schmitt trigger 4-in NAND gates to provide a latch enable output (and its complement) whenever any of \$R_1\dots R_4\$ goes **LOW**.

[image]

\$LE\$ will be used by the 8-bit latch (coming up.) \$\overline{LE}\$ will be used by a `data avail` FF (also coming up.)

#### data available signal

It helps to provide a signal to indicate when a keypress has been captured. I'd use this:

[image]

It's simple enough. However, depending upon how things power up (I'm not feeding this the POR signal) it may falsely signal a data available output. When first starting up, it's a good idea to just toggle the \$CLR\$ (which should normally be kept **HIGH** and toggled **LOW** to clear the data available signal.)

#### row and column data latch

This is pretty easy and accepts a rising edge on \$LE\$ to trigger the latching event. This will capture both the row and the column. (The active row and active column will be read as **LOW**, with the remaining bits hopefully **HIGH**.)

[image]

#### completed system

All put together, it's this:

[image]

It's been some time since I've built one of these (decades and decades ago), back when using an MCU wasn't really an option and things had to be done this way. (And the above isn't what I built, then.)

Today, of course, an MCU would wipe the floor of something like what I've presented above. You should definitely considering using an MCU, instead. But perhaps you need the above to convince yourself of that. So there it is.

Best wishes.

P.S. Feel free to add those optos. I left that part for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain a whole new way to approach this problem, it will definitely come in handy for any future (and purely-ish? digital) projects.
Take care sir

Comment: @lachoprime Will do. Thanks for the kind words! And you take care, too!